# @OneToOne-Relation with "is not null"

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA2, Unitils, jUnit + other stuff.
My problem concerns two entities:

```
@Entity
public class CaseStuff implements Serializable {
....
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long caseStuffId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "CaseStuff")
private XCase xcase;
...
}

@Entity
public class XCase implements Serializable {
....
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CASESTUFFID")
private CaseStuff caseStuff;
....
}
```

Both tables got the ID of the other table, so it could also be mapped the other way around.
In a jUnit-Test, Unitils inserts one CaseStuff record with no XCase. I confirmed, that it really is null.
BUT, then I use the following query:

```
"select s from CaseStuff s where s.xcase is null"
```

and it returns 0 CaseStuff objects. Doing the same with "is not null" returns the object, but when inspecting CaseStuff.xcase while debugging, it is clearly null.

Any idea, what's going awry here?

EDIT:
The SQL generated by Hibernate translates to

```
select
    *
from
    CaseStuff casestuff0_ 
where
     (
        casestuff0_.xcaseid is null
    )
```

*Replaced all field names by *

EDIT2:
Before I changed it to a OneToOne-Relation, it was an unneccessary ManyToOne.
Previously the jUnit test had the query

```
"select s from CaseStuff s where not exists (select x from s.xcase x)"
```

This still works correctly for some reason, as if s.xcase was still a Set.

Thanks to all who try to figure it out with me.

Comment: see the exact sql thats getting executed by hibernate

Comment: Good thinking, but found nothing interesting (see edit).

Comment: Can you check the database and see the values that have been actually inserted in the table row?

Comment: Not with my example, since Unitils inserts that in the transaction used by the jUnit-Tests. Therefore, no commit happens and I cannot see it when accessing the DB via SQL Developer. I checked by querying before usage and looking at the values in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

As you defined your entities Xcase will have the foreign key

So Xcase  table beside it's id will have caseStuff_id (or other name) as foreign key to the Xcase id.

Like in this image (make abstraction of the names)

[image]

In your case Person is Xcase and  CaseStuff is PersonDetails

So probably you CaseStuff table (if it was generated by the persistence provider does not have a case id)

Please check on the db level to see how your tables are defined, structurally speaking.

Comment: The tables were not generated by the persistence provider. As mentioned above, the tables have each others ID, but the entities hold each other as object.

Comment: Then you have not a bidirectional relationship, you have two unidirectional one to one relationships. Don't use mapped by ...use JoinColumn for both